# Spring : creating beans with @Bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an issue with beans creations :

```
@Bean
Service carService() {
  return new Service(new CarRepository(), "car");
}
```

My issue is that `CarRepository class` has a dependency to `EntityManager em` variable (with `@PersistenceContext`)

So if I use `new` operator, I'm missing this dependency (because I'm instanciating myself the bean).

Also I have many services (CarService, BikeService etc...) and many repositories too (CarRepository, BikeRepository etc...). So using annotations directly in classes seems difficult.

So any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Pass your repository as dependency into your Bean factory function:

```java
@Bean
Service carService(final CarRepository carRepository) {
  return new Service(carRepository, "car");
}
```

The repository needs to exist as a bean itself. You can create the repository bean in another bean method of a configuration class, or by annotating the class and having it created during component scanning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to annotate every repository class with `@Repository`
annotation. And every service class with `@Service`.

Comment: The problem is : I have one service class and many repositories implementations. So I need to select a different repository for each service. I fail to do that with Service and Repository annotations

Comment: Maybe you can use '@Qualifier'? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

Comment: You can name the repositories e.g. 
`@Service("service1")`
`@Service("service2")`

Then when you intject them:
`@Autowired`
`@Qualtifier("service1")`
`Service serviceOne;`

Answer (score 1):

In Spring you should not use the new operator for Services. Use the annotation

```
@Service 
public classSomeClass {
```

or

```
@Component
public classSomeClass {
```

and your class can be injected via depnendency Injection.
If you want to create a new custom bean that can be used via dependencyInjection This is what the @Configuration annotation is for.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass{

    @Bean
    public SomeClass createSomeClass(){
      return new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your configuration example, the `@Bean` annotation is missing on the createSomeClass method.